# How to get PDF file URL uploaded in system.xml. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, system.xml, file

I'm trying to upload *PDF file* via `system.xml` my code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="infozzle" translate="label" sortOrder="11">
            <label>Infozzle Extension</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="infozzle_productpagecustom" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Product PDF File</label>
            <tab>infozzle</tab>       
            <resource>Infozzle_ProductPageCustom::config_productpagecustom</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Setting</label>
                    <field id="custom_file_upload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>PDF File Upload</label>
                    <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">pdf</upload_dir>
                </field>
                
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

n my *Helper Function* is

```
public function getPDFfile()
    {
        $getarray = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('infozzle_productpagecustom/general/custom_file_upload',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $getarray;
    }
```

so when I get the file using *Helper* in *phtml* like

```
echo $helper->getPDFfile();
```

then it returns me
`Asad's Resume.pdf,application/pdf,/tmp/phpDGlEAI,0,65105`
 While When I tried to *Delete* the existing file it is not deleting n adding more *files*
[image]
how can I get the exact `url` of the file n why it returns such ambiguous result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem has been sorted we need to add  `<backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File</backend_model>` in `field` like

```
<field id="custom_file_upload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
       <label>PDF File Upload</label>
       <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File</backend_model>
       <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">pdf</upload_dir>
</field>
```

and after that we need to add class

> Vender\Module\Model\Config\Backend\CustomFileType

```
<?php
 
namespace Vender\Module\Model\Config\Backend;
 
class CustomFileType extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
{
    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions() {
        return ['pdf'];
    }
}
```

in my case I want *PDF* thats why I return `pdf` you can change it to `csv` or anything else